# How to use a select element to insert a Thymleaf fragment?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to use an HTML select element to change which thymeleaf fragment is displayed.

the html code:

```
<label for="algorithm">Algorithm</label>
<select id="algorithm" onchange="getAlgorithmParams(this.value, '#algParams')">
    <option value="">Select Algorithm</option>
    <option value="ZeroR">ZeroR</option>
    <option value="OneR">OneR</option>
    <option value="NaiveBayes">Naive Bayes</option>
    <option value="IBK">IBK</option>
    <option value="J48">J48</option>
</select>

<div id="algParams"></div>
```

The javascript code:

```
getAlgorithmParams = function (algorithmName, elementID){
    console.log(algorithmName);
    console.log(elementID);
    document.querySelector(elementID).innerHTML = "<div th:insert='~{/fragments/parameter-fragments :: " + algorithmName + "}'></div>";
}
```

when the selection is changed i want the div element with the id "algParams" to display a different thymeleaf fragment. When i run it, it shows this in the page elements when i inspect the page.

```
<div th:insert="~{/fragments/parameter-fragments :: OneR}"></div>
```

which is the correct notation and should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf renders the HTML on the server side. Once the HTML is in the browser, Thymeleaf is no longer "active".

What you can do is insert the `<div>` for each of the options hidden on the page and use JavaScript to make the one that is selected visible.

So your Thymeleaf template has:

```
<div class="hidden">
  <div id="ZeroR" th:insert="~{/fragments/parameter-fragments :: ZeroR}"></div>
  <div id="OneR" th:insert="~{/fragments/parameter-fragments :: OneR}"></div>
  <div id="NaiveBayes" th:insert="~{/fragments/parameter-fragments :: NaiveBayes}"></div>
  <div id="IBK" th:insert="~{/fragments/parameter-fragments :: IBK}"></div>
  <div id="J48" th:insert="~{/fragments/parameter-fragments :: J48}"></div>
</div>
```

Which will render out all those fragments in the HTML that is sent to the browser.

Then in your JavaScript function, select the div you need via the `id` and set that as `innerHTML`.